# Issues with colour in plots

Tags: r, plot, graph, colors

I'm trying to do a plot (from a vector) and coloring based on the values of one of the columns. This is the code that I have.

```
plot(x = FishVector$Diagonal.Length..cm.,
     y = FishVector$Diagonal.Width..cm., 
     main = "Relación entre largo del pez y el ancho",
     xlab = "Largo del pez(cm)",
     ylab = "Ancho del pez(cm)",
     col = FishVector$Species,
     pch = 20
)
```

I'm receiving this error msg:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid color name 'Bream'
```

Bream is one of the values for the column Species.

Comment: For base R plots, `col=` needs to be a valid color name. It looks like you are passing in fish names which are not color names.  You could convert to factor which would result in numeric values for colors: `col = factor(FishVector$Species)`. That will use the values from `palette()` as colors

Comment: _MrFlick_  is right, you probably learned that method where the respective column is integer which might be what is confusing you now.